# Swift - Unwind Segue triggering error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using for the first time the Unwind Segue approach. I have multiple view controllers as can be seen in the picture below (a few of them shown of course). In the Edit Profile I have a Done button. Once clicked I trigger an IBAction that triggers an unwind segue.

Here is the code for the Done button in the nav bar:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainViews(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    //let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToMainSegue", sender: self)        
}
```

and in the

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
```

I am doing the following to pass data from Edit Profile back to Home View

```
if (segue.identifier == "unwindToMainSegue") {
    // pass data to next view
    let tabCtrl = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
    let destinationVC = tabCtrl.viewControllers![0] as! HomeViewController
            destinationVC.userObject = self.userObject;
}
```

When segue identifier is matched and code is executed (to transfer userObject from this controller to another), it triggers the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'app.EditProfileViewController' (0x100b99d80) to 'UITabBarController' (0x104a1d030).

How can this error be fixed? I am surprised since i am casting to UITabBarController so thought it should work.

[image]

Comment: sorry not sure I understand what you are proposing

Comment: You don't return to the UITabBarController, you return to the ViewController that triggered the original segue.

Comment: ok...since I am new to unwinding...can you tell me how can I modify it to return to the view controller that triggered the original segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return to the UITabBarController in an *unwind segue*.  You return to the ViewController that triggered the original segue, or one if its ancestors.

As @jlehr stated in the comments:

> Unwind segues don't return to anything; they dismiss any pushed and
>   presented view controllers between the source and destination view
>   controller. The destination is wherever the implementation of the
>   unwind method is found, regardless of how the source view controller
>   was presented.

To unwind to the viewController that triggered the original segue, you need to implement the `@IBAction func returnToHere(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)` function in the viewController you want to return to.

Then when you set up your *Done* button by dragging to the *Exit* icon, you select `returnToHere` from the pop-up.

To pass data back to the sourceViewController, give your *unwind segue* an identifier such as "unwindToSource", then override `prepareForSegue` in the viewController you are returning from:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToSource" {
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! SourceViewController
        dvc.userObject = self.userObject
    }
}
```

Comment: ok...this is different than the approach I took probably the reason for the error. But can you explain how I can pass back data to source view controller using your approach?

Comment: I did the changes and tested...it actually updated the data automatically. This is strange behavior in my opinion. But I guess this is how it works. Thanks

Comment: Saying "You return to the ViewController that triggered the original segue" is  misleading. Unwind segues don't return to anything; they dismiss any pushed and presented view controllers between the source and destination view controller. The destination is wherever the implementation of the unwind method is found, regardless of how the source view controller was presented.

Comment: @jlehr, that is correct. I was addressing their implementation where they believed the destination of the unwind was the UITabBarController. You are absolutely correct that the unwind can remove multiple view controllers between the source and the destination and that the destination is wherever the unwind method is found. It of course must be in the call chain.

Comment: @jlehr, thanks for pointing out that I was misleading in my language.  I incorporated your comment in my answer because it was very clearly stated.